# Select all results from table1 as well table2 in mysql where both table has one common id

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have 2 tables.

table1 structure

```
id | status_type | status_content | 
1  | image       | abc            |       
2  | text           | def            |        
3  | video       | ghi            |
```

table2 stucture

```
|file_id | status_id | file_name |
 | 1      |   1       | image.png |
 | 2      |   3       | video.mp4 |
```

and I want all results from both tables. e.g.

```
id | status_type | status_content | file_id | file_name |
1  | image         | abc            |  1      | image.png |
2  | text        | def            |   blank      |   blank        |
3  | video       | ghi            |  3      | video.mp4 |
```

Comment: SO isn't really a free code writing service and shouldn't really be treated as such

Comment: @halfer A year ago maybe. The moment's passed.

Comment: No worries @Strawberry - I'm not too worried about one question, though I would urge you not to avoid closing questions just because they are old. There is a lot of closeable material on the site, and it can always do with a clean-up `:-)`.

Comment: @halfer I would urge you to start with the present, and work your way backwards.

Comment: Thanks for the mutual urging, @Strawberry!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT table1.id,table1.status_type, table1.status_content,
     table2.status_id,table2.file_name,
     FROM table2
     INNER JOIN table2
     ON table1.id=table2.file_id ;
```

A join can help you.

Comment: thank you for reply. i found my solution. i used firstly tried full join. it did not work for me. so i use the left join and right join and combine the result.